# Increase number of rows of dataframe with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

This is a little subset of the data :

I have :

```
DPT CITY   ID1  ID2                 Ct_value1           Ct_value_2           suspicion
02   Mpl  EDE1  A2074 A2093 B3045   28.24 24.21 28.35   24.21 23.24 24.45     analytic`
04   Txl  EDE2  A234 A345 A356      23.45 23.42 25.44   21.98 23.43 24.34     clinic
05   Erl  EDE3  A347                23.67               25.56                 clinic
03   Mpl  EDE4  A234 B456           22.34 34.24         45.35 42.34           analytic
```

my wish is to increase the number of rowsaccording to the number of informations in the cell contained in the ID2 variable. For example, if I have 3 values in ID2 separated by a space, this should result in 3 lines or one line per different ID2 in the new dataset, as follows :

```
DPT CITY   ID1  ID2     Ct_value1   Ct_value_2 suspicion
02   Mpl  EDE1  A2074   28.24       24.21      analytic`
02   Mpl  EDE1  A2093   24.21       23.24      analytic              
02   Mpl  EDE1  B3045   28.35       24.45      analytic
04   Txl  EDE2  A234    23.45       21.98      clinic
04   Txl  EDE2  A345    23.42       23.43      clinic
04   Txl  EDE2  A356    25.44       24.34      clinic
05   Erl  EDE3  A347    23.67       25.56      clinic
03   Mpl  EDE4  A234    22.34       45.35      analytic
03   Mpl  EDE4  B456    34.24       42.34      analytic
```

I now have 9 rows in new dataframe instead of 4 previously and I would like the information to be the same for the other variables such as suspicion or city.
Anyone see the issue? Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

using **tidyverse**

try like this

```
library(tidyverse)

separate_rows(data = df, ID2, Ct_value1, Ct_value_2, convert = TRUE)
```

using **data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, list(ID2 = tstrsplit(ID2, " "),
          Ct_value1 = tstrsplit(Ct_value1, " "),
          Ct_value_2 = tstrsplit(Ct_value_2, " ")),
   by = list(DPT, CITY, ID1, suspicion)]
```